# Proper Indy Setup with Docker

Tags: docker, installation, identity, hyperledger-indy

I'm getting into Hyperleadger Indy for a project and want to set it up as a clean docker container. Its often pretty confusing with correct sources of documentation.

As a start i wanted to follow the tutorial based on Alice.

I used https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/ as a repository and installed it with commands from https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/#how-to-start-local-nodes-pool-with-docker.

Everything worked but when i try to enter the CML this happens:

```
indy@a1265007869d:/$ indy
Loading module /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/config/config-crypto-example1.py
Module loaded.
This client is deprecated! Please, use the new libindy-based CLI: https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/tree/master/cli

Indy-CLI (c) 2017 Evernym, Inc.
Type 'help' for more information.
Running Indy 1.4.66
```

Any command throw:

```
Exception in callback PosixAsyncioEventLoop.run_as_coroutine.<locals>.stdin_ready() at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit/eventloop/asyncio_posix.py:65
handle: <Handle PosixAsyncioEventLoop.run_as_coroutine.<locals>.stdin_ready() at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prompt_toolkit/eventloop/asyncio_posix.py:65>
```

Can someone maybe also explain when to use Indy-Node and when Indy-SDK and are they independent?

Answer (score 0):

Embedded indy-node CLI is deprecated now. There are two options:

1. Try another terminal client or the same client with different window size
2. Move to CLI from `indy-cli` separated package. You cand find it here https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-sdk/blob/master/cli/README.md

Comment: But how do i get the indy-cli package in my Docker Setup? Clone it from inside the docker?

Comment: Install it by instruction from the answer above on one of container with node, separate container in the same network or host machine (you must be sure that node's IP addresses are available from indy-cli location)